# Coinbase button creation and callback

Tags: php, api, button, callback, bitcoin

Im trying to create a button and assign a callback URL with coinbase.

I'm getting some CAPTCHA data returned when trying to post to coinbase API.

I think my webhost is getting blocked by CloudFlare, disabling my code.

Here's what I have:

```
<a class="coinbase-button" data-code="<?php

$data = array(
  "button" => array(
    "name" => "Ticket",
    "price_string" => "0.01",
    "price_currency_iso" => "BTC",
    "custom" => $OrderNext . "- " . $ticket,
    "callback_url" => "https://x.com/callback.php",
    "description" => "Ticket - " . $ticket ,
    "type" => "buy_now",
    "style" => "buy_now_large"
  )
);                                                                    

$json_data = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init("https://coinbase.com/api/v1/buttons?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
  'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

if( ! $output = curl_exec($ch))
  {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    } 

$result = json_decode($output);
```

`$output` returns a CAPTCHA page.

`$result` is null.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $output looks like this when I echo.: http://s10.postimg.org/3pll2rt1l/Cloud_Flare_error.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Brian from Coinbase here.  It looks like you are hitting the API to generate a new payment button for each page load which, depending on the amount of traffic you get, could trigger our rate limiting either internally or through CloudFlare.

We currently have the merchant create button api limited to 10,000 calls per day internally, for example, for most merchants.

A better approach would be to hit the API once for each product (or if the price changes) and store the resulting 'code' parameter. If you save this in your database you can reuse it on every page load.  This will help your pages load faster also.

More details: https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/buttons/create.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I never used coinbase but have you checked if your host does have curl support enabled in phpinfo()? Or maybe curl_init / curl_exec is in the list of disabled functions.

**EDIT:**

you're using a https url, you must either provide the CA certificate to be checked against setting the flag **CURLOPT_CAINFO**, or disable the verification of the certificate setting the **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** to false.

Comment: Thanks! OK, so I added this after CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER:

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CA.crt");

It fixed my CAPTCHA problem, but now all the return values are null.

Comment: Have you tried setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, to check if the problem is indeed with the https ?

Comment: When I set VERIFYPEER to false, I get the CAPTCHA screen again. I think the SSL is required.

Comment: So, I discovered that I'm failing the SSL Verify. ssl_verify_result=0.

Comment: OK, so i think i got the right SSL certificate and ultimately it does that same thing as when I disable the SSL completely. It returns a CloudFlare page that requires a CAPTCHA. Looks like this:

Comment: One more step
Please complete the security check to access coinbase.com
Refresh Announce Info
reCAPTCHA challenge image
Enter above text Leave a message for the site owner? (100 characters left)
Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?

Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.
What can I do to prevent this in the future?

Comment: If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.

If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.

CloudFlare Ray ID: b35c0d38158032a • Your IP: 33.33.33.4 • Help • Performance & security by CloudFlare

Comment: Its returning a 403 HTTP Forbidden message. =/

Comment: That's really odd, it seems is really related to coinbase or between your webhosting and coinbase itself, and not a php configuration. Or maybe the API has changed and you are missing some flag. I'm out of ideias.

Comment: I tried to change to the blockchain.info API and I also get the exact same reCaptcha response from their servers. Both APIs are on CloudFlare. I wonder if this is a CloudFlare issue, a webhost issue, a Coinbase/blockchain issue, or a PHP coding issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use code like this for generating button for payment

```
   $apikey ="***************"; 
   $apisecret = "************************";
   $nonce = sprintf('%0.0f',round(microtime(true) * 1000000));

   $url = "https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/v1/buttons?nonce=" . $nonce;

   $parameters = [];
   $parameters["button"]["name"] = "Checkout Invoice";
   $parameters["button"]["custom"] = $orderId;
   $parameters["button"]["price_string"] = $priceString;
   $parameters["button"]["type"] = "buy_now";
   $parameters["button"]["subscription"] = false;
   $parameters["button"]["price_currency_iso"] = "USD";
   $parameters["button"]["description"] = "Checkout Invoice";
   $parameters["button"]["style"] = "custom_large";
   $parameters["button"]["include_email"] = true;
   $parameters["button"]["callback_url"] = url("bitcoin/callback");
   $parameters = http_build_query($parameters, true);



  $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $nonce . $url . $parameters, $apisecret);

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $url,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
           "ACCESS_KEY: " . $apikey,
           "ACCESS_NONCE: " . $nonce,
           "ACCESS_SIGNATURE: " . $signature
       )));

   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $parameters,
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
   ));

   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   $decodeResponse = json_decode($response);
```

It will return to button code for payment on coinbase.